# SVG: how to correct for off-centered markers with bezier curved paths?

Tags: html, svg, bezier, markers

## Context

I want to get an arrowhead on a path to a node in a graph that I am making. Because I am using bezier curves it is easier to use the center of the points to / from which the path ends / starts respectively.

In the attached JSFiddle (below) we see a simple triangle of points, one of which is the control points for a quadratic bezier curve. In addition the end markers have been offset to make contact with the node rather than being partially behind it; this is due to paths being drawn to the centers of the points rather than the edges.

Aesthetically there are a few things not quite right with this drawing:

- the tip of the arrow head is thiner than the path
- although the tip is angled correctly for the arrowhead on the bezier curve, the path is not centered at the point the arrow head appears.

These aesthetic flaws occur because:

- the point of an arrow head is obviously thiner than a path / the path extends through the node
- the arrow head is so large in respect to the curvature of the path, there is no satisfactory solution to the arrow head problem (given the current code)

Now one could jury-rig the second issue by making a tight cubic bezier curve as done in the second SVG of the JSFiddle.

However, as seen in the third SVG, this does not work with extreme curvature either.

## Questions

Is there either a simple way to ensure that the angle of the arrow-head's point and positions of the path when the arrow head joins are centered; alternatively a way to simply scale the arrow head to be small enough where one would not notice?

Is there a way to make the path starting at the arrowhead to the end invisible? / alternatively a simple way to get paths to end prior to hitting the node?

```
# code to meet SO requirements
# look at this code
```

## JSFiddle

[SVG Marker Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/SumNeuron/Lg7tyL5q/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific application, try adding a viewBox to the marker to make it smaller so it looks somewhat aligned with the end of the bezier. (SVG markers do not currently align with curves.)  Change refX to 'slide' the arrow a bit forward to the end of the line.
e.g.

```
<marker id="arrow" viewBox="0 0 25 25" markerWidth="20" markerHeight="10" refX="20" refY="5" orient="auto" markerUnits="strokeWidth">
```

Comment: How does the view box work. It works on the first one, but not so great on the other. Is there a way to get markers render last (so that way I can layer the image as paths, nodes, markers)?

Comment: SVG elements are always stacked/rendered  the same as when they are created. i.e. your circles should be created first if you want the paths/arrows above them.

Comment: One of the main issues is that I am using the center of `circle`s for making the `path`s and then placing the `circle`s on top of the `path`s to mask the `path`s. I do this because in my application, I may not necessarily know which direction the `path` may be coming from, so figuring out how to end the `path` right before the `circle` is non-trivial. I can shift the `marker` back on the `path` by adding the radius to the `refX` attribute, but then the `path` is wider than the tip. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: To meet the requirement of the bezier, plus adjust the refX offset for the circle, and not have the path stroke width mess up the point of the arrow will require fine tuning on your part of also  viewBox, path stroke-width, arrow stroke-width and circle stroke-width.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make the markers use your coordinate system, instead of strokeweight:

```
<marker id="arrow" markerWidth="40" markerHeight="30" refX="25" refY="-5"
                   orient="auto" markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse" overflow="visible">
  <!-- path for the arrow head -->
  <path d="M-18,10 l 6 -15 l -6 -15 l 40 15 l -40 15 Z"
        fill="white"
        stroke='black'
        stroke-width='3'
        opacity='1' />
</marker>
```

Sorted. If we draw the paths *after* the "points" so that the arrow heads end up on top:

[image]

Comment: I have no idea what that means... also, the image doesn't show :(

Comment: you can notice `markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse"` - and the image loads just fine, unless you're using browser extensions that block it.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something: how is showing you a simple change to your markup that effects centered arrows not answering "Is there either a simple way to ensure that the angle of the arrow-head's point and positions of the path when the arrow head joins are centered"?

Comment: Because as evidence in the image above, as well as the more extreme example (number 3 in the attached fiddle), while `markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse"` does a much better job at alignment, it is not perfect, which is further evident by using the original proportions of the marker given, whereas the one in your example is wider (masking this issue further). It is a good answer, and please do not mis-understand, I do appreciate it. I just do not know enough about svg to understand exactly how this change to `markerUnits` works, nor why it is not infallible.

Comment: ah, I see, gotcha.